# Calling an address array in web3 returns an error that the method needs arguments

Tags: solidity, web3js, arrays, error

I'm declaring a public address array in my contract, but when I call it, I get an error saying it's expecting an argument. Can someone shine a light on what is happening here?

Contract.sol

```
uint public buyIn;
address[] public playersRegistered;
```

index.js

```
// this works
console.log(await contract.methods.buyIn.call());

// this throws an error
console.log(await contract.methods.playersRegistered.call());
```

Error message:
`Unhandled Rejection (Error): The number of arguments is not matching the methods required number. You need to pass 1 arguments.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that solidity creates getters for public variables but if the variables are referenced variables it does not return the value as expected. Instead you need to pass the index for the array to get the value of specific index. To get the complete array elements you need to write the getter for array. let me show you the contract for this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;
contract Test {
   uint [] public players ;
    constructor() public {
        players.push(1);
        players.push(2);
        players.push(3);
    }

    function getArray() public view returns (uint[] memory){
       return players;
    }
}
```

So when you will try to call the getter for public array variable from `web3` without giving the `index` it will throw an error because argument for function call will not match. See below the running example of the above contract to under more.

[image]

Hope you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity creates getters for public variables and requires an index for arrays. Answer found here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/60491/48494